# How To Load A Collection inside A model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been trying  to achieve something like in Backbone:

```
Pages =[
    {
        id:1, 
        title:"Page Title", 
        subPages:[]//This will hold subPage Collection from /pages/1/subpages/
   }
   .
   .
   .
   ]
```

But I 'm unable to achieve this and every tutorial I follow, just gives basic examples.

What is the proper way to load a collection in my other model?

regards,

Comment: Jey, did my solution not work for you? If so, can you provide more info?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've created a SubPageCollection class elsewhere:

```
subPages: new SubPageCollection();
```